# Python didn't find any duplicate value even when append the same df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dummy df like this and save it into csv,

```
    date      time       open       high       low        close      volume
0  2021-05-06  04:08:00  9150090.0  9150090.0  9125001.0  9130000.0  9.015642
1  2021-05-06  04:09:00  9140000.0  9145000.0  9125012.0  9134068.0  3.121043
2  2021-05-06  04:10:00  9133882.0  9133882.0  9125002.0  9132999.0  5.536345
3  2021-05-06  04:11:00  9132999.0  9135013.0  9131000.0  9132999.0  5.880620
```

after that, I try to simulate appending new data stream by appending the same csv and try to remove (if any) duplicated data

```
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    df_old = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='UTF-8')
else:
    df_old = pd.DataFrame()
df_stream = df_old.append(df_new).drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])
df_stream.to_csv(filename, encoding='UTF-8', index=False)
```

df_stream still returned with duplicated value

```
print(df_stream)
   date        time      open       high       low        close      volume
0  2021-05-06  04:08:00  9150090.0  9150090.0  9125001.0  9130000.0  9.015642
1  2021-05-06  04:09:00  9140000.0  9145000.0  9125012.0  9134068.0  3.121043
2  2021-05-06  04:10:00  9133882.0  9133882.0  9125002.0  9132999.0  5.536345
3  2021-05-06  04:11:00  9132999.0  9135013.0  9131000.0  9132999.0  5.880620
0  2021-05-06  04:08:00  9150090.0  9150090.0  9125001.0  9130000.0  9.015642
1  2021-05-06  04:09:00  9140000.0  9145000.0  9125012.0  9134068.0  3.121043
2  2021-05-06  04:10:00  9133882.0  9133882.0  9125002.0  9132999.0  5.536345
3  2021-05-06  04:11:00  9132999.0  9135013.0  9131000.0  9132999.0  5.880620

print(df_stream.duplicated())
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
```

How to resolve this issue?
i try with `df_stream[~df_stream.index.duplicated(keep='last')]` data returned with no consistency (shuffled, removed previous data, etc)

Answer (score 1):

After simulate appending new data stream by appending the same csv and storing the data in the df, we can apply
drop_duplicates over df.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

**Input after reading csv having duplicates**

```
d="""date,time,open,high,low,close,volume
2021-05-06,04:08:00,9150090.0,9150090.0,9125001.0,9130000.0,9.015642
2021-05-06,04:09:00,9140000.0,9145000.0,9125012.0,9134068.0,3.121043
2021-05-06,04:10:00,9133882.0,9133882.0,9125002.0,9132999.0,5.536345
2021-05-06,04:11:00,9132999.0,9135013.0,9131000.0,9132999.0,5.880620
2021-05-06,04:08:00,9150090.0,9150090.0,9125001.0,9130000.0,9.015642
2021-05-06,04:09:00,9140000.0,9145000.0,9125012.0,9134068.0,3.121043
2021-05-06,04:10:00,9133882.0,9133882.0,9125002.0,9132999.0,5.536345
2021-05-06,04:11:00,9132999.0,9135013.0,9131000.0,9132999.0,5.880620"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df
```

**Input df**

```
    date    time    open    high    low close   volume
0   2021-05-06  04:08:00    9150090.0   9150090.0   9125001.0   9130000.0   9.015642
1   2021-05-06  04:09:00    9140000.0   9145000.0   9125012.0   9134068.0   3.121043
2   2021-05-06  04:10:00    9133882.0   9133882.0   9125002.0   9132999.0   5.536345
3   2021-05-06  04:11:00    9132999.0   9135013.0   9131000.0   9132999.0   5.880620
4   2021-05-06  04:08:00    9150090.0   9150090.0   9125001.0   9130000.0   9.015642
5   2021-05-06  04:09:00    9140000.0   9145000.0   9125012.0   9134068.0   3.121043
6   2021-05-06  04:10:00    9133882.0   9133882.0   9125002.0   9132999.0   5.536345
7   2021-05-06  04:11:00    9132999.0   9135013.0   9131000.0   9132999.0   5.880620
```

**Output**

```
date    time    open    high    low close   volume
0   2021-05-06  04:08:00    9150090.0   9150090.0   9125001.0   9130000.0   9.015642
1   2021-05-06  04:09:00    9140000.0   9145000.0   9125012.0   9134068.0   3.121043
2   2021-05-06  04:10:00    9133882.0   9133882.0   9125002.0   9132999.0   5.536345
3   2021-05-06  04:11:00    9132999.0   9135013.0   9131000.0   9132999.0   5.880620
```

Comment: if i input the data manually it worked, to clarify I used two different csv (each have 4 rows of data) then i put it in `df_old` and `df_new` then i do `df_stream = df_old.append(df_new).reset_index(drop=True)` to simulate your result but after `df_stream = df_stream.drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])` it wont drop anything, then i try to change the drop column `df_stream = df_stream.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'])` it returned only index 0 and 4, you can view it here [https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vMx9hXKcbz8SDawTnHbzpV6JiRZsEuVP?usp=sharing]

Comment: Logically when you provide `df_stream.drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])` it should drop duplicate rows of `time` column, as per example it should return top 4 rows. When you are running `df_stream = df_stream.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'])` it should provide only 0th index row as all the rows in `date` column have duplicate values. if you want to remove all duplicate rows of df then why are you using `subset arg`?

Comment: i agree with you if using `df_stream.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'])` should only returned index 0, but why it also returned index 4? I use `subset arg` because the `df_new` will have overlapping data with `df_old` so I check duplicated value and drop it